# retrieve data from table based on a foreignKey Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

So I have 2 tables, articles and sub_categories. They are linked throug Eloquent: articles has many sub_categories's, and sub_categories belongsTo article. They are linked with foreign keys as such: in "article" categorie_id.

How do I retrieve the entire table data article where categorie is "DOG" for exemple
Sorry for the abstraction, but this is the best way I can explain it? :D

article model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Articles extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User') ;
    }

    public function sous_categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\SouCategories') ;
    }
}
```

sub_categorie model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class SouCategories extends Model
{
    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories') ;
    }

    public function articles() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Articles','cat_id') ;
    }
}
```

in my controller i am trying to fetch data based on the foreign key on the sub_category  and foreach sub category i am creating an a array like the mainslider contain articles that have a certain sub_category

```
public function index()
{
    $infos = Infos::all();
    $categories = Categories::all();
    $articles=Articles::all();   
    $mainslider=Soucategories::with('articles')->get();
    foreach($mainslider as $record){
        dd($record->articles);
    }
    die();
    return view('frontEnd.homepage',compact('infos','categories','articles','mainslider'));
}
```

Comment: Can you post your relationship from your models? and the code you have already tried?

Comment: I have updated my answer can you try and let me know, if you are getting any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the code you have posted it should be something like

```
Soucategories::where('title', 'DOG')->with('articles')->get();
```

it seems there will be only on Soucategory with name "DOG", so you can do something like

```
Soucategories::where('title', 'DOG')->first()->articles
```

Comment: i 've got this error Trying to get property 'articles' of non-object

Comment: @saifeddinejebri Do you have name field with value 'DOG' in your Soucategories model, if  yes, can you post the record, or check `var_dump(Soucategories::where('name', 'DOG')->get())`.

Comment: Soucategories::where('title','test')->with('articles')->get(); give me empty collection

Comment: @saifeddinejebri the field name is `name` or `title` ?

Comment: also Soucategories::where('name', 'DOG')->get() give empty array

Comment: @saifeddinejebri what are the fields in `Soucategories` model table?

Comment: the field name is title and my data base is not empty

Comment: Schema::create('sou_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: if field name is `title`, why you have written `name` in your question?, if there is any record with `title` `DOG` post that record here, so that I can help you.

Comment: sorry i just give an exemple , like name = dog but in my case title=dog

Comment: @saifeddinejebri  What you are getting for `Soucategories::where('title','dog')->get()` ?

Comment: @saifeddinejebri Can you confirm there is any record in `sou_categories` table with `title`='dog' ? also consider letter case?

Comment: thank you Prafulla , i just found a solution Article::whereHas('sub_categories', function($query) {
            $query->where('title', 'DOG');
         })->get();

Comment: it retreive the articles that have dog value in sub_categories , but if you can help i want to sort them with creation date , i already have a field called "created_at"  type date

Comment: @saifeddinejebri use `sortBy('created_at')->get()` instead of only `get()`.

Comment: @saifeddinejebri if it helped you , you may like to upvote it and if it solved your problem, you can both upvote and accept this as answer.